# Styling messes up after pushing navigator to page

Tags: flutter, dart

When I push my navigator to any new page, the styling is completely messed up. The font is bigger than my future, red and yellow underlined.
[look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukBL8.png)

Here is my push:
[image]

Why is this happening? I am using macOS/Desktop, I don't know if that matters.

Thanks.

When I add my page (widget) to another page, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's highly likely you are missing a **material parent** widget (like a `Scaffold`). Though, this is not 100% sure.

Can you edit your question to add more details? I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need a `Scaffold` widget when pushing a new route in order to get things proper as you expect, wrap the `DesktopAccountPage_Subpage` with a `Scaffold` widget:

```
Scaffold(body: DesktopAccountPage_Subpage(...)),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `Scaffold` as root widget in Inside **DesktopAccountPage_Subpage** class as below

if the **DesktopAccountPage_Subpage** is Stateless widget then

```
Scaffold(body: child);
```

if the **DesktopAccountPage_Subpage** is Stateful widget then

```
Scaffold(body: widget.child);
```

Where **child** the is passed parameter in **MaterialPageRoute**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, you are right! The problem was that I didn't wrap a Scaffold around the page.

Again, thanks to all of you.